# Isolation Tree algorithm question about classification

Tags: random-forest, anomaly-detection, isolation, isolation-forest

In the part where we create the trees (iTrees) I don't understand why we are using the following classification line of code (much alike as it is in decision tree classification):

```
def classify_data(data):

label_column = data.values[:, -1]
unique_classes, counts_unique_classes = np.unique(label_column, return_counts=True)

index = counts_unique_classes.argmax()
classification = unique_classes[index]

return classification
```

We are choosing the last column and an indexed value of the largest unique element? It might make sense for decision trees but I don't understand why we use it in isolation forest?

And the whole iTree code is looking like the following:

```
def isolation_tree(data,counter=0,
                   max_depth=50,random_subspace=False):
# End loop if max depth or if isolated
if (counter == max_depth) or data.shape[0]<=1:
    classification = classify_data(data)
    return classification
    
else:
    # Counter
    counter +=1
    
    # Select random feature
    split_column = select_feature(data)
    
    # Select random value
    split_value = select_value(data,split_column)

    # Split data
    data_below, data_above = split_data(data,split_column,split_value)

# instantiate sub-tree
question = "{} <= {}".format(split_column,split_value)
sub_tree = {question: []}

# Recursive part
below_answer = isolation_tree(data_below,counter,max_depth=max_depth)
above_answer = isolation_tree(data_above,counter,max_depth=max_depth)

if below_answer == above_answer:
    sub_tree = below_answer
else:
    sub_tree[question].append(below_answer)
    sub_tree[question].append(above_answer)
    
return sub_tree
```

Edit: Here is an example of the data and running classify_data:

```
feat1     feat2
0  3.300000  3.300000
1 -0.519349  0.353008
2 -0.269108 -0.909188
3 -1.887810 -0.555841
4 -0.711432  0.927116
label columns: [ 3.3         0.3530081  -0.90918776 -0.55584138  
0.92711613]
unique_classes, counts unique classes: [-0.90918776 -0.55584138  
0.3530081   0.92711613  3.3       ] [1 1 1 1 1]
-0.9091877609469025
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure I fully understand the situation, but I'll assume that `data` essentially contains predictions from multiple classifiers (since you speak of a forest). With that assumption the function makes sense to me. Since the code basically does "the final classiciation is the class that the majority of classifiers agree on" . `unique_classes` is e.g. `[0,1,2,3]` and the counts (think of it as votes) is e.g. `[2,30,0,0]`, then class `1` has the majority vote. Did I understand this correct?

Comment: Usually you have labeled classes in the last column, but in our case we don't have this since we are using iTrees (unsupervised, nonlabeled data.) So why we are choosing the last column for the classification is beyond my understanding. Thanks for the reply

Comment: It would be helpful if you included an example of the input (and maybe expected output) as well :)

Comment: Could you add it to the question with some formatting? :)

Comment: Yea sorry I added it to the original post instead formatted!

Comment: Well, I agree now that the function doesn't make much sense. I am really not sure what that function is trying to do given the data. I would expect it to do a calculation of many anomaly scores rather than what it does now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we will further try to explore this and hopefully find a decent answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I later found out that the classification part was for testing purposes, it is worthless. If you use this code (popular on Medium) please remove the classification function as it serves no purpose.